# jQuery tile placement in grid with two sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css

This question will be very hard to ask... I hope I ask this right. I have been wrapping my head around this for far too long now.  I am trying to make a responsive tile design.  The tiles may have one of two sizes of height; featured and not featured.  I would like to be able to place them in columns (and for the purpose of this, let's just say in 3 columns)  Here's the html after load:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card featured">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card featured">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card featured">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card featured">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
</div>
```

Featured tiles are double the height of non-featured cards.  I am using jQuery to place these cards.  The last piece of code I was using places all of these tiles in the appropriate rows and columns, though it does not account for these featured cards - here's the code that I got from here earlier today:

```
var columns = 3;

$('.card').each(function(i){
    var row = Math.floor(i / columns);
    var col = i % columns;
    $(this).addClass('col' + col + ' row' + row);
});
```

this will give the appropriate column and row count to each element.  But it won't account for the featured cards being larger.  I need to be able to move a tile to the next column if the space is occupied by the bottom of a featured tile.

I would like these tiles to be placed like this:

```
 __   __   __
|1 | |2_| |3_|
|  |  __   __
|__| |4 | |5_|
 __  |  |  __
|6 | |__| |7_|
|  |  __   __
|__| |8_| |9 |
 __   __  |  |
|10| |11| |__|
```

You can see an example of what I'm doing [Here](http://beta2.mybattlereport.com/collective.php)(I'm working on this live so it might change, but I will revert back to this when I am finished). As you can see in that page, I am just making every nth tile in it's own column.  My problem is; when I have several featured tiles in one column, it pushes more relevant cards lower than less relevant ones.

I need to refactor my code, starting with a list of divs.

Please ask any questions.

**UPDATE** Solved - Please ask if you care to know. The answer is extensive